# PowerPointer - Can't print multiple slides per page using "print on both sides" option

Tags: office365, powerpoint

I am trying to print a PowerPointe document with multiple slides per page and i want to print on both sides. As soon as i press "print", even when the printer is disconnected, i get an error saying `"We found a problem with your printer setup and couldn't print"`. When the printer is connected exactly the same thing happens so i think the problem is somewhere in PowerPoint.

I've attached one screenshot where i get the error and the other one where i opened the print menu right before clicking "print".

Thanks in advance

[The print option:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUhb7.png)

[The error i get (even with disconnected printer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcODj.png)

Comment: It seems more likely that there is a problem with your printer or the connection to it rather than how PowerPoint is dealing with your selected options.  In any case, this question really belongs in the SuperUser forum, not StackOverflow (which is for questions about *writing*, not *using* software.

Comment: But i get the error even when the printer is disconnected, and i can print from another computer. That means that even if PowerPoint remembers my printer config even when it's offline the issue has nothing to do with the printer since from another computer i am able to print what i want on the same printer.

Comment: Naturally you'll get the error when the printer's disconnected and the fact that you can print from another printer tells you nothing about problems with THIS computer's connection to the printer.  Can you print to the same printer from other applications on THIS computer?

Comment: No, i meant that i can print on the same printer from another computer. Which means that the problem is somewhere in the pc or probably in PowerPoint, since from a third computer with the same powerpoint i couldn't print (same printer in all cases).

Comment: Which then suggests that most likely you have one properly configured computer and two misconfigured ones. Again, this is the wrong forum for questions like this; please ask in SuperUser (and I'd suggest that you try my suggestion of printing from other apps on the problem computer first, and mention the results of that test)